# TypeError: xmlHttp.overrideMimeType is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple typescript code that is using XMLHttpRequest like this:

```
function request(callback){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        callback(xmlHttp.responseXML);
    else if (xmlHttp.status==404) {
            console.log("XML could not be found");
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", myURL, true); 
    xmlHttp.responseType = 'document';
    xmlHttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function readData(sData) {

    //console.log(jsonResponse.list[0]);
    console.log(sData)
 }
request(readData)
```

When I run this script I keep receiving the error message:
    "TypeError: xmlHttp.overrideMimeType is not a function".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tested your code and apart from `myURL` being undefined it didn't throw the error you specified. https://jsbin.com/dizeyilena/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: it is a global variable in my code

Comment: You are using which browser? @atlan

Comment: I use Chrome on Mac