# Creating an array from files in a folder and sending them randomly

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a command for a Discord.js bot that when triggered, will use an array created from a folder, select a random image, then send it.

I can't set the array manually because the amount of images in the folder is always going to be changing.

This is what I have:

```
if(command.toLowerCase() == "command"){

    const fs = require('fs');
    const imageFolderLocation = "./images/";
    var imageArray = [];

    fs.readdir(imageFolderLocation, (err, files) => {
      imageArray = files;
    });

    let randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length) + 1;

      for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
        message.channel.sendFile(randomImage);
      }
    return;
  }
```

I tried starting the bot with `--trace-warnings` but it was to no avail. No warnings printed to console.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I see:

- fs.readdir is async, you cannot use files/imageArray outside of the callback
- you send the random int instead of an image
- you send the randomImage imageArray.length times
- you ignore err

Corrected code:

```
if (command.toLowerCase() == "command") {

    const fs = require('fs');
    const imageFolderLocation = "./images/";

    fs.readdir(imageFolderLocation, (err, imageArray) => {

        // TODO if (err) { /* print to console or something */ }

        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length) + 1;
        let randomImage = imageArray[randomIndex];

        message.channel.sendFile(randomImage);
    });

    return;
}
```