# how to get discord.js to pick a random image from file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm in another pickle I've realized over the past week that my images are not loading due to the fact the links have expired so I wanna find out how to go about using a file directory in the code.

Here's what I've tried:

```
});
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith('L!hug')) {
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\images\hugs')
/* now files is an Array of the name of the files in the folder and you can pick a random name inside of that array */
let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)] 
    }
});
```

and

```
});
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith('L!hug')) {
const path = 'C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\images\hugs';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file => {
ranfile = Math.floor(Math.random() * file.length);
message.channel.sendFile(ranfile);
})
}
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Getting an array from folder and sending a random file with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50851030/90527)", "[Creating an array from files in a folder and sending them randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254973/90527)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out through searching and searching but found a answer the modified it to this, i hope people use this in future reference!
`` const num = (Math.floor(Math.random()* 5)+1).toString();     message.channel.send({files: [`./slap/slap${num}.gif`]}) ``

Answer (score 1):

Using fs.readdirSync('./images/') instead of fs.readFileSync('./images/') works easier, but then you will have to create the folder inside of VSC and put the images in the folder, you can also drag and drop the images into the solution and use:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(`./images/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.png'))
```

so that when it looks for an image, it doesn't select anything else. hope it helps for some people.

Answer (score -1):

Happy to help.

You're using FS the wrong way. This Is What It Should Look Like :D Also Here Is Some Documentation on It ( https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/fs.html ).

-- Code --

Also Just As A Tip! I See You Are Using Full Directories, That's Quite Innificeng (E.g if You Change Your Username, Drive ID, etc.) so in fs provided the image is in the same folder you can just do ./(ImageName), or if it is in the same folder but under another say /FBIBot/Images you can do ./Images/(ImageName). ^^

--

What The Error Was: (I Unfortunately Cannot Test it But I Am Like 99% Sure).

You Were Using `fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file => {` When You Were Meant To Be Using `fs.readfilesync(path).forEach(file => {`.

-- First Code --

});

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith('L!hug')) {
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readfileSync('C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\images\hugs')
/* now files is an Array of the name of the files in the folder and you can pick a random name inside of that array */
let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)] 
    }
});
```

-- Second Code --

```
});
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith('L!hug')) {
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readFileSync('C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\images\hugs')
/* now files is an Array of the name of the files in the folder and you can pick a random name inside of that array */
let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)] 
    }
});
```

^^

Comment: hi dr space
these methods were unfortunately unsuccessful it keep coming up with this error for both code

Comment: for both code
`internal/fs/utils.js:227
    throw err;
    ^Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:Users
evbwDesktopgamesFBIBotimageshugs'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:446:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:348:35)
    at Client.<anonymous> `

Comment: Ah, all good! Where I said you can do ./Folder/ImageName As The FS Directory I May Have Been Wrong. If The Script is In The Same Folder As Your Image Try Doing ./Imagename.

Let Me Know How It Goes :D

Comment: Would that still do the random imaging or would that only pull out one image?

Comment: Sorry For The Wait! Give This A Shot. Sorry For Any Messy Code. I Had To Code This Quickly. (Yes This Does Include Random Imaging As Last On Did Not. This Was Taken From Code 2.) The https://github.com/MrDrSpace/TheCoolCodingCave

Let Me Know How This One Goes!

Comment: heyyo 
i got this
``internal/fs/utils.js:227
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read``

Comment: That's a directory error. Try just pasting the full directory.

Comment: Hey! You got anything?

Comment: Oh I forgot to try it out I’ll give it a try soon (I’m at work atm)

Comment: heyy 
i got this error
``    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:Users
evbwDesktopgamesFBIBothugs/hug1.gif'``

Comment: It's because you are using the wrong directory, That's not a code issue. Make sure you have the right one set in the FS call.

Comment: Hey! You got anything on this?

Comment: unfortunately this 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:Users
evbwDesktopgamesFBIBothugs/hug1.gif'

Comment: Hey! Sorry, Haven't Been On in Like a Week. You Should Literally Just Be Able To Copy and Paste The Link Under 'Properties' By Right Clicking On The File -> Properties and Copying The 'Location'.

It is still an unfound directory error.

:D

Comment: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:522:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:337:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:374:19)
    at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\bot.js:206:18)
    at Client.emit (events.js:224:7)
  errno: -4068,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EISDIR

Comment: Hey! Sorry, it took so long. Try changing fs.readfile to fs.readfilesync. 

:D

Comment: Is your antivirus blocking the directory? That should work. No reason for it not to. You are literally just copying and pasting the directory.

Comment: Hey! I am sorry but I really don't know what to do from here. I really would like to help but I am not at your PC to see the code. Here is an example of the code used for reading a file that might help.

// Code
[THERE WAS CODE HERE BUT IT WAS IN PARAGRAPH FORM. I Put It On Github To Make It Easier To Read For You :) https://github.com/MrDrSpace/TheCoolCodingCave/blob/master/fileReadingCode.js]

Apologies for the delays. Life has been... Busy. Hope This Helps!

Comment: Hey! That Link is Broken. Use this :D https://github.com/MrDrSpace/TheCoolCodingCave/blob/master/fileReadingCode.js

Comment: heyyo 
im now getting the the error
`TypeError: fs.readyFileSync is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\bot.js:208:18)`

Comment: Hey! :O Sorry! My bad. Meant fs.readFileSync  ! Hope this helps :D

Comment: lol all g but its now coming up with this 
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/hugs'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:446:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:348:35)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\bot.js:208:18)`

Comment: Hey! That means you have an invalid directory. Remember if the file you are looking for is in the same root folder as that script you can place a . in front of it.

Otherwise, try a different directory.

Thanks

Comment: Heyyo not working I did ./hug and ./hug/.gif and /.hug there’s two files in the hug folder

Comment: Hey. You're not meant to put the . in front of the file name. Just in front of the of the first slash.

Comment: this is the code ```client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content.startsWith('L!hug')) {
  let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
  if (!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to hug them!!');
 // const fs = require('fs')
  let image = fs.readFileSync('./hugs') 
  console.log(image); //(That will just print gibberish but you get the idea that you could put that into something else.
  message.channel.send(`${targetMember.user}, You just got a hug!`)
 }
});```