# How do I get a Random Image from my Local file and place it on Embed in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do I make my attachment look from each files in ./src/ that has starts with `pingping`and would randomly choose an image for example: `pingping2.gif` I tried doing something like

```
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); //I got 5 because I have 5 pingping[].gif files. I dont know how it could count how many files startsWith('pingping')..
attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(`./src/pingping${rand}.gif`);
```

for some reason it only shows the last image from all the files instead of choosing randomly..
Here is the whole file -->

```
 attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./src/pingping1.gif');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    cooldown: 5,
    description: 'Just a Ping Command',
    execute(message, args){
        let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();        
        if(!args[0])
        return message.channel.send('Pong!');
        else{
            let pingEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(`Ring Ring ${targetMember}!!, ${message.author.username} is Pinging you!!`)
                .setColor("#EB338B")
                .attachFiles(attachment)
                .setImage('attachment://pingping1.gif')
            message.channel.send(pingEmbed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Getting an array from folder and sending a random file with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50851030/90527)", "[Creating an array from files in a folder and sending them randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254973/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

I have a command in my discord bot that sends random gifs the only downside is that you have to use direct links (honestly im not sure about that but didnt try it with files)

`const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)]`
and then add the direct links example: `` const messages = [`link 1,`link 2`,`link 3`] ``
then it should send a random link

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it on a bot that sends an image every hour

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('./src');
let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
if (chosenFile.contains("pingping")) {
    message.channel.send({ files: [{ attachment: `./src/${chosenFile}` }] }
}
```