# Sending random file with discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello I have a question.

How can a discord bot send a file with random name. This file is in a specific directory and it's only 1 file.

What's the code that allow the bot know that is the file.

```
message.author.send("HTML:", {
    files: [{
        attachment: 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/specificFolder/fileisHere',
        name: 'filename.html'
    }]
})
```

how can this code change that the bot allow send randomly file

Comment: you’re asking how to pick one file of some directory instead of define specific filename. is that correct?

Comment: yeah let's suppose the bot download a file with random name from the internet like this file: d28f69e7-3179-43e0-be82-fc45a2d534f2.html
and after the user use the commend the bot should send that file in a specific dir

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Getting an array from folder and sending a random file with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50851030/90527)", "[Creating an array from files in a folder and sending them randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254973/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

First, prefix each file with a number, incrementing by 1 each time and starting at 0 e.g

```
0file.txt
1file.txt
2file.txt 
... etc
```

Then when you call the get random file function read each file in turn, and generate a random number from `0` to `number of files you have - 1` and output the filename.

```js
const fs = require('fs') //require fs to open files etc

//read files from the directory - I chose a directory called `dir001`
fs.readdir("./dir001", (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  let dirFiles = files.filter((f) => f.split(".").pop() === "txt"); // if the files end with txt - change for your needs

  if (dirFiles.length === 0) {
    console.log("No dir files found"); //if no files found return
    return;
  }

  let randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * <number of files in the dir>); // generate random number from 0 to number of files in the dir

  dirFiles.forEach((f) => {
    if (!f.startsWith(randInt)) return; // if the file doesnt start with randInt(), return
    message.channel.send(`random file: ${f}`); // output the randomized file
  });
});
```

This should work, please let me know if you get errors, after making sure you changed everything to your individual needs.

Comment: what if the is like that :d28f69e7-3179-43e0-be82-fc45a2d534f2.html
the dir folder contain 1 file only with random number a letters like the above

Comment: that was not what you asked the question about, please append your question, as I have clearly wasted my time