# Getting an random image from a folder discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi I am trying to fetch a random image out of a folder and make the discord bot send it. When I type the command I get the following error: (node:15184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'c:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\discordbot2\t.png'

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
client.on("message",message=>{
  if(message.content==('image')){
    console.log("image")
    var files = fs.readdirSync('folder')
    var chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)] 
    console.log(chosenFile)
    message.channel.send(
      {
        files : [
          chosenFile
        ]
      }
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: can you debug it? do you know if `files` actually get the files from the right folder? 
also, is `c:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\discordbot2\` the right folder? wonder if it could be a file permissions issue

Comment: You are generating an invalid path, there could be a number of things wrong, without additional information it will be hard for us to help.

Comment: Which one actually exists ? `c:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\discordbot2\t.png` or `c:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\discordbot2\folder\t.png` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Getting an array from folder and sending a random file with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50851030/90527)", "[Creating an array from files in a folder and sending them randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254973/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

The pathname you pass to `message.channel.send()` in the `files` option is just the file name. It's supposed to be a path (relative to the current directory, or absolute), which is how it's interpreted. As the chosen file isn't in the current directory, it generates the ENOENT "no such file or directory" error.

To make a relative path, you can use `path.join`, passing the both the path to the directory holding the file and the file name:

```
const path = require('path');
...
    message.channel.send({files: [path.join('folder', chosenFile)] })
```